# PHP and JavaScript: Reload captcha image

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, captcha, partial-page-refresh

I've made my own captcha class in PHP, just to learn. It's ok, working as I want. I've tried to add a "refresh image" button but I don't know how do I do that.

form code:

```
<p><img src="img.php" alt="Captcha!" /></p>
```

img.php code:

```
<?php
require_once 'captcha.class.php';
$captcha = Captcha::instance(10);
echo $captcha;
?>
```

__toString method:

```
public function __toString()
{
    ob_start();
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($this->drawImage(), null, 100);
    return ob_get_flush();
}
```

These code will output the captcha. How could I refresh this image? Something in AJAX would be great!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you checking the captcha is correct when the form is completed? Session variable?

If it is a single session variable, you could just refresh the image using plain javascript. Adding a random query string to the end of the image url would avoid any caching issues.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have the reload make an AJAX call to a page that creates a new captcha, the return the newly created result into a DIV?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function reload()
    {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'img.php';
        var x = document.getElementById('captcha');
        x.src = img.src;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript: reload()" >Reload</a>
<img src="img.php" alt="Captcha!" id="captcha" />
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe a plain `x.src = 'img.php'` would do the trick but just to be shure it get's a new request i've made it using another image ( it allso gives you a bit more to search/learn ) .

Comment: I always get the same image. What about cleaning the cache? I will try that, thank you.

Comment: not shure if it will correct you're bug but make shure you set the headers in the past when you output the image from you're class . smth like `header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past` i suppose would do the trick

Comment: You need to actually set it to a different URL, not just a different variable name (which is pointless). I suggest something like `'img.php?random=' + Math.random()`.

Comment: or , you could change `img.src = 'img.php';` to `img.src = 'img.php?rand=' + Math.random();` , that way you make shure no the browser actualy makes a request to the server since it's a totaly different url than the previous one ( no need to worry about any $_GET values in you're php

Comment: No way man! I've tried it but it doesn't work. I still receive the same image. Thank you.

Comment: Does img.php return a diferent image each time it's requested ?